# how to create a code template in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

so I want to create a short cut/ template for a few very frequent code lines
such as

```
System.out.println("someVariablesInExistingScope as String ===>>>" +someVariablesInExistingScope);
```

so if I can create a template or short where i just type my shortcut
such as
shrtcut + CTRL + SPACE

and it types the above mentioned line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a live template. You can do so in the Settings dialog (Settings | Editor | Live Tempates).

See the [IntelliJ IDEA help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) for more information.